# Why using Boolean Mesh node material is ignored?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I have a mesh, and I want to extrude a part of it. Editing the mesh is not what I want (first of all is a big mesh), I want it procedural.

[image: GN Boolean Mesh]

Now I loosed the material in the resulting mesh...

Any way to solve this?

Thanks...

EDIT 1: Set Material node doesn't work for me...

[image: edit1-1]

[image: edit1-2]

[image: edit1-3]

Answer (score 1):

When Blender performs a boolean operation, it normally takes the material from the face which originally occupied that position if that material is available, so both source objects contribute some materials to the result.

When you're cutting into one object with another object, all of the 'new' faces 'made' by the cut (which are more accurately faces partially or totally copied from the cutter)  are going to inherit the material from the cutter, not the source object.  That being said, the source object needs to have the inherited material available on a slot so that the new faces can be set to that slot.  There are addons that may do this for you but by default this has to be configured somewhat manually.

Unfortunately, geometry nodes seems to do something a little different.  Here are some hopefully useful results:
[image: First node setup]

This shows a default cube being cut by a node created cylinder geometry.  There is a muted set material node on the cutter which will be important later.  Also of note is that the base cube has two material slots, each linked to a different material - one black and one teal.

With this setup, the cutter has no material set and so the new mesh has entirely the first (black) material slot across its entire surface.  If the set material node on the cube is changed to teal, something a little unexpected happens: [image: second setup, cube changed to teal]

In this case, the outside of the result (that was originally from the cube) has changed to teal as we expect.  However, the inner faces from the cylinder cut are still black.  This implies that the boolean is actually going on slot index rather than what actual material is used.  A further followup test (and the original odd case that prompted this deeper investigation) is what happens when we apply a material to the cutter - any material, the result is the same.  This screenshot shows the cube back to black, and the cut faces are now showing teal - but both the cube AND the cutter were specifically set to use the black material!
[image: Third setup, initially unexpected teal here]

It doesn't matter what the material in the set material node for the cutter is, the output will always be teal, but the set material node does need to exist, as otherwise it will be black (see image 2).

As far as I can tell what happens is that the mesh boolean node reads the cutter and determines it has a material slot at all, discards what's actually in that slot, but increments the material slot on the result.  The actual materials are pulled from the original object.

One more images just to confirm this - Adding a third orange material to the cube, we can control that being applied to the cut faces by adding two set material nodes to the cutter, and making them different materials.  It will not become orange (remaining teal) if they are the same, as that would not cause the cutter to have two material slots - you need to have both set to something different for it to result in it referencing the third slot.

[image: How to get to a third slot]

Without knowing how the slots are set up a specific instruction of what to fix on your own mesh is difficult, but if you have multiple slots, removing them all down to one slot is probably a good start.  If that doesn't change anything, look to the UV mapping if applied to the texture.  Using object coordinates with appropriate scaling in a mapping node instead of the UV coordinates might be more successful when dealing with procedural geometry.

Comment: I´d tried Set Material node at the beginning of this issue with no success... I'd edit the question with images.

Comment: @Olivier I've updated my answer with more detail after further experimentation.  Turns out I was wrong about how geometry nodes specifically handles booleans and materials, which is pretty unintuitive and doesn't match how manual or modifier booleans work as far as I'm aware.  In short, you need to do things with material slots on the original object, and also potentially add extra material slots on the cutter.

Comment: Oh!! What a detailed answer/investigation... Awesome... I really appreciate it.. Thank you so much.. BTW sorry by the delay, family issues. I will check it during this weekend, here is 4am.. Again, thank you..